# How to display from first page when we are trying to display a PDF file in html using Object tag

Tags: html

I have an object tag where am trying to display some reports which are located in my application. Here is my sample code:

```
<object data="Reports/Submitted/<%=reportname%>_<%=tdate%>.pdf#toolbar=1&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=1&amp;page=2&amp;view=FitH" type="application/pdf" width="100%"height="100%">
                        <p>It appears you don't have a PDF plugin for this browser. No biggie... you can <a href="/Reports/Submitted/<%=reportname%>_<%=tdate%>.PDF">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p>
                    </object>
```

when i try to dislay it is displaying pdf file but problem is it is displaying from second page rather than from first page. I require some suggestion how to go about.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you have there an href, the second page, is in the same path that the first page?

Comment: That anchor tag is used when user is not able to view that pdf file in the browser then he can see directly from the href path specified. Here in object data is the element which is picking file from the location and displaying. So by default it is displaying 2nd page in the browser through that code.

Answer (score 0):

Just change page=1& or remove it. So that it will take by default first page.

```
<object data="Reports/Submitted/<%=reportname%>_<%=tdate%>.pdf#toolbar=1&amp;navpanes=0&amp;scrollbar=1&amp;page=1&amp;view=FitH" type="application/pdf" width="100%"height="100%">
```